# Custom Media query across application

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am using `angular7` app with the `bootstrap 4.2.1`. there is no.of breakpoints the bootstrap has, but i require only 3 break points. so i changed in 3 break points like this:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';

$grid-breakpoints: (
    sm: 320px,
    md: 767px,
    lg: 1024px
);

$container-min-widths: (
  sm: 320px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    body{
        background:green;
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    body{
        background:yellow;
    }
}
```

Now my app only has 3 break points and `min` widths. when i write a class property for `md` it applies in `lg` as well. what is wrong here. how to customize in to 3 breakpoint and write the properties to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap's documentation here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints I found that `media-breakpoint-up` means `min-with` not max-with.

**From documentation:**

*Hide starting at `min-width: 0`, and then show at the `sm` breakpoint*

```
    .custom-class {
      display: none;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
      .custom-class {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

I think you should use `media-breakpoint-only` as bootstrap says:

> There are also media queries and mixins for targeting a single segment
>   of screen sizes using the minimum and maximum breakpoint widths.

For example this

```
@include media-breakpoint-only(sm) { ... }
```

means

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }
```

Also check out `media-breakpoint-between`.

I hope I gave some help.